# Stop propagation in fullcalendar select callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I'm developing a calendar using Fullcalendar [(docs)](http://fullcalendar.io/)

When an empty time slot is selected i want to show a context menu, like this:
 (don't mind the styling)

```
select: function(start, end, jsEvent){    
    $("#calendarContextMenu").css({
        display: "block",
        left: jsEvent.pageX + 4,
        top: jsEvent.pageY - 16
    });
}
```

And hide it when anything else is clicked:

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $("#calendarContextMenu").hide();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RobinvdA/e6v3mkjo/3/)

This works well, but when an allday time slot is selected the context menu doesn't show up. I noticed this happens because `$(document).click()` is fired directly after fullcalendar's select callback. What can i do to fix it? It seems like there's some sort of event bubbling going on. Ofcourse, alternate solutions are always welcome.

Note: There is a div `.fc-content-skeleton` which is causing the problem i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your codes and added the `eventClick` listener. Kindly check here: http://jsfiddle.net/e6v3mkjo/4/

**Update 1**:

Changed `eventClick` to `dayClick`

http://jsfiddle.net/e6v3mkjo/5/

Kindly check their docs as well: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/

**Update 2**:

Haha, I realized I didn't understand the question well. The solution to your real problem is just simple: remove the document click handler and then add the `unselect` handler.

```
unselect: function() {
  $("#calendarContextMenu").hide();
}
```

Comment: In your example, when you select an event, the context menu shows up. This shouldn't happen. Also, when an allday event slot is clicked, the context menu doesn't show up, which is what my question is about ;)

Comment: Changed `eventClick` to `dayClick`

Comment: After update 1: Thanks for your replies. However, this does not answer my question. When i click an allday time slot, it still doesn't show the context menu.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know there was an unselect callback. I really should read docs better...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).click(function(){
   console.log('hide');

    $("#calendarContextMenu").show();
});
```

Comment: I didn't put this in my question, but when anything other than a timeslot is clicked, the context menu should hide